# Issue with mysql import file .sql in local, due to the language encoding

Tags: mysql, encoding, character-encoding, localhost

When I import a sql file from a server I get strange characters. I want to believe it's encoding. I am writing the values of the server bd and the local bd:

SERVER:

```
collation_connection: utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database: utf8_spanish_ci
collation_server: utf8_general_ci

character_set_client: utf8mb4
character_set_connection: utf8mb4
character_set_database: utf8
character_set_filesystem: binary
character_set_results: utf8mb4
character_set_server: utf8
character_set_system: utf8
character_sets_dir: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\charsets\
```

LOCAL

```
collation_connection: utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database: latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server: latin1_swedish_ci

character_set_client: utf8mb4
character_set_connection: utf8mb4
character_set_database: latin1
character_set_filesystem: binary
character_set_results: utf8mb4
character_set_server: latin1
character_set_system: utf8
character_sets_dir: C:\xampp\mysql\share\charsets\
```

File SQL import contains this script:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `prueba` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci */;
USE `prueba`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pruebaTable` (
`co_pruebaTable` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`co_pruebaTable`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=418630 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;
```

When I import database in my local, column "name" in "pruebaTable" contains rare characters but in server database i see this data correctly

I have tried to change this variables with this queries, but it do not work:

```
set collation_database=utf8_spanish_ci;
```

What can be the solution? I need see this data correctly when i import this file sql. I open this file with notepad++ and i can see data correctly. The codification .sql is: UTF-8, so the problem should be encoding to local database, i think

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column definition overrides the table definition, which overrides the database definition.  The column definition is not the problem.

How are you doing the "import"?  If it is with `LOAD DATA`, use the clause in it that establishes the `CHARACTER SET` for the load.

Do you establish a character set when connecting?  Do you use `SET NAMES utf8;`?  Something else?

See "Mojibake" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Let's debug this from the other side...  What "strange characters" do you get?  What is the result of `SELECT HEX(name) ...` for the strange text?

F1   C3B1 
`ñ` is hex `F1` when encoded in latin1`, hex`C3B1`when correctly encoded in utf8 (or utf8mb4), or hex`C383C2B1`when it shows as`Ã±` for "double encoding".

Answer (score 0):

Try to alter your DB:

`ALTER DATABASE prueba CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci;`